# Are microsoft IIS configuration tags case sensitive?

Tags: xml, iis, configuration, webserver

I have a question regarding the configuration of Microsoft IIS.

All its configuration files (`ApplicationHost.config`, `machine.config`, `web.config`, etc.) are in XML format. A configuration reference is given here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/

My question is: Are the tags generally case sensitive, or case insensitive? The documentation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.ftpserver/security/authentication/#configuration-sample

shows e.g. the `authentication` section being uppercase, while it is defined to be all lowercase.

Comment: XML is always case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can report documentation bugs (or send pull requests) to Microsoft as that article includes obviously incorrect sample code.

IIS configuration elements (tags in your words) are strictly case sensitive (while some settings might accept an input value in incorrect casing).

Comment: Do you have a reference which states that these tags are strictly case sensitive? I couldn't find that, which is why I asked here.

Comment: @Albert Microsoft has no reference for you. Invalid casing leads to invalid configuration file (500.19 if you run a web page), so probably that's just common sense.

Comment: Created https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/iis-docs/issues/580 btw